# How does Scala do type matching if all types are erased at compile time?

Tags: scala, type-erasure

Per [Scala's documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html), *Scala’s types are erased at compile time*. How does it do type matching then? For example, how is this match statement possible:

```
myVar match {
  case x: Bar => ???
  case x: Foo => ???
  case _      =>
}
```

Certainly, the byte code needs to be able to retain some information about `myVar`'s type or class.

Comment: *Some* type information is erased, not all.

Comment: https://blog.knoldus.com/2018/04/02/type-erasure-in-scala/

Comment: That statement in the docs is very confusingly phrased.

Comment: I also don't quite understand where [the spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#type-erasure) says that type erasure of a concrete not-parameterized class is just this class. It seems to omit this base-case as self-evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type arguments to type constructors are erased. There are no type constructors in your example, therefore nothing is erased.

Note that even though type arguments are erased, you can explicitly ask for a `TypeTag` in order to reify it.